Restsharp v110 update Rest Client
I'm looking to migrate to v110 of Restsharp (from v106).
All looks OK so far bar I'm unsure how to update the Rest Client once initialised.
We are running api automation and have an initial method to initialise the client with code below.
RestClient restClient = new RestClient(baseUrl)
Then in subsequent methods we assign the property values to the RestClient. For instance;

Toggle Automatic Redirects
restClient.FollowRedirects = true;

Add Cookie Container
restClient.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();


The issue now I have is if I try code in 1 and 2 now with say restClient.Options.CookieContainer I get an error that the values cannot be assigned to.
I can try below;
var options = new RestClientOptions(){ CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()} restClient.Options = new RestClient(options)
But I don't think I should be creating a new RestClient each time.
Would anyone know what is the best option to assign values to an existing client?

You cannot change options for an existing instance of RestSharp as it makes the client not thread safe.
For the cookie container issue, RestSharp doesn't use cookie container for making calls. If you want, you can add a cookie container to RestRequest instance. In general, you don't need to do it.
